# Make <span> move to new line

Tags: html, css, newline

I'm trying to make it so I can change the style of one word in the h2 - Magazine. I set a span to do this, but cannot get it onto a new line (that is still in line with the rest of the text).

```css
.left h2,
.right h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.left h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
}

.right h2 {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(132, 132, 238);
}

.magazine {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="rectangle right">
    <h2>TOAST<span class="magazine">Magazine</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: column;` to `right h2`

```css
.left h2,
.right h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.left h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
}

.right h2 {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(132, 132, 238);
  flex-direction: column;
}

.magazine {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="rectangle right">
    <h2>TOAST<span class="magazine">Magazine</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.magazine { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Span is inline element so you should set **display : block;**

Answer (score 0):

Ah, wait, got it -

CSS:

`.right h2 { display: block }` 
`.magazine { display: block }`